# C++: fmodf() & fmod() - Strange Results?

Tags: c++, posix, modulo, gettimeofday

So, I needed a way to be able to get the second of the day, so I messed around with `fmod()` & `gettimeofday()` (Mac OSX). However, I came into some odd results along the way:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cmath>

class A {
public:
    static float secondOfDayFmodF()
    {
        timeval t;
        gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

        return fmodf((t.tv_sec) + (t.tv_usec / 1000000.0), 86400);
    }

    static float secondOfDayFmod()
    {
        timeval t;
        gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

        return fmod(((t.tv_sec) + (t.tv_usec / 1000000.0)), 86400);
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << "fmodf:\t" << A::secondOfDayFmodF() << endl;
        cout << "fmod:\t"  << A::secondOfDayFmod()  << endl;

        // sleep for 1 s
        sleep(1);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Output:

> fmodf: 5760
>   fmod:   5699.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5700.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5701.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5702.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5703.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5704.17
>   fmodf:  5760
>   fmod:   5705.18
>   ...

So, why does the `fmodf()` version give me the same output every time, where the `fmod()` version gives the expected result (changing after the `sleep()` call)? Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: You might like to see [latest publicly avaliable draft of the C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-precision floats don't have enough precision to store all the bits in `(t.tv_sec) + (t.tv_usec / 1000000)`. If you wait long enough (2 minutes about), you'll see a big jump.

Comment: Gosh darn golly ghee whizz you are right! That's very interesting, thank you for the insight!